# Get IPv4 Address using JavaScript on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, ip, ipv4

I'm creating a web application and in order for it to run, you must have your device 'registered'. The registration process involves entering the IPv4 address of the device you wish to use into a field which updates the database.
When accessing the application, it goes through a `window.webkitRTCPeerConnection` or `window.mozRTCPeerConnection` check to get the IP address. This works on the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. So, I had to use ActiveX if the IP wasn't obtained from the RTCPeerConnection check.
My problem is that I want Safari to be able to run the application, but I can't seem to find anything on how to get the IPv4 address for devices running Safari.
To clarify, this web application is not open for general public usage and we'll have complete control over what's installed on devices running the application. (That's my justification for using ActiveX).
Any suggestions and/or references to how I can do such a thing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This API can get your IP adress.

https://l2.io/

More advanced solution:
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/

This one also supports Safari, according to this: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/#Browser_Support

The last one is in my opinion the best one. I use that one in one of my projects.

EDIT:
On safari there is no support yet for WebRTC Connections. So it is not possible to obtain the local IP adress on safari.

Comment: This seems really good, but it gets the public IP address rather than what I'm looking for which is the local address of the device (192.168.x.x).

Comment: I've already tried using RTCPeerConnection which works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But sadly it doesn't work in Safari so I can't use this method for it.

Comment: Yes i just saw safari didnt implement WebRTC connections yet. So i think it will be difficult to do this. I will see if i get it somehow working on Safari. If i will, i update my answer ASAP :)

Comment: Updated. Its impossible yet with safari. I gues public IP is your only solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>
            Demo for:
            <a href="https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips">
                https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips
            </a>
        </h4>
        <p>
            This demo secretly makes requests to STUN servers that can log your
            request. These requests do not show up in developer consoles and
            cannot be blocked by browser plugins (AdBlock, Ghostery, etc.).
        </p>
        <h4>Your local IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <h4>Your public IP addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <h4>Your IPv6 addresses:</h4>
        <ul></ul>
        <iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
        <script>
            //get the IP addresses associated with an account
            function getIPs(callback){
                var ip_dups = {};
                //compatibility for firefox and chrome
                var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                    || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                    || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
                if(!RTCPeerConnection){
                    //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
                    //
                    //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                    //<script>...getIPs called in here...
                    //
                    var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                    RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                        || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                        || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                    useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                }
                //minimal requirements for data connection
                var mediaConstraints = {
                    optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
                };
                var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};
                //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
                var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);
                function handleCandidate(candidate){
                    //match just the IP address
                    var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                    var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];
                    //remove duplicates
                    if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                        callback(ip_addr);
                    ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
                }
                //listen for candidate events
                pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){
                    //skip non-candidate events
                    if(ice.candidate)
                        handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
                };
                //create a bogus data channel
                pc.createDataChannel("");
                //create an offer sdp
                pc.createOffer(function(result){
                    //trigger the stun server request
                    pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});
                }, function(){});
                //wait for a while to let everything done
                setTimeout(function(){
                    //read candidate info from local description
                    var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');
                    lines.forEach(function(line){
                        if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                            handleCandidate(line);
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }
            //insert IP addresses into the page
            getIPs(function(ip){
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.textContent = ip;
                //local IPs
                if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);
                //IPv6 addresses
                else if (ip.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/))
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2].appendChild(li);
                //assume the rest are public IPs
                else
                    document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].appendChild(li);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sadly didn't work on Safari. I've already tried to use RTCPeerConnection but it doesn't work as it does on Chrome and Firefox on Safari.

Comment: What might cause not to get the public ip? I'm testing the demo, I get the local and IPv6 but not the `public` ip. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The website https://api.ipify.org knows your ip adress. The only thing you have to do is scrape it. You can do that with JavaScript.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.ipify.org", false);
xhttp.send();
var ip = xhttp.responseText;
```